# Clustering and kmeans have unclear documentation

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means, feature-detection

I have to use kmeans in my future work, I know it is available in OpenCV as they have a [documentation page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#double%20kmeans%28InputArray%20data,%20int%20K,%20InputOutputArray%20bestLabels,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20attempts,%20int%20flags,%20OutputArray%20centers%29) on it.

I cannot make sense of the format displayed, it has also not been explained in the given details below (it appears to be details related to OpenCV 1.1). I mean, with the C++ line:

```
double kmeans(InputArray data, int K, InputOutputArray bestLabels, TermCriteria criteria, int attempts, int flags, OutputArray centers=noArray() )
```

what datatype is data, vector or matrix? which is the input matrix, which will be the output?

I am used to reading documentation [like this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=featuredetector#featuredetector-detect) where it is clearly stated which is the input/output/flag etc and what data types they are.

```
C++: void FeatureDetector::detect(const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give a short example of kmeans being used.

P.S. the input matrix I have ready to be used for kmeans is the one produces by `DescriptorExtractor::compute`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find examples of using most of `OpenCV`'s functions in folder `samples`. In your situation take a look at these two:

1. `kmeans.cpp`
2. `matcher_simple.cpp`